# Create a function for creating variables (EditText, Button) Java Android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to short the code of creating a EditText in java?

Example

```
EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputField);
```

Instead of writing the whole code can we wrap it to a function like:

```
public static CreateItem(String Type, String name, String id) {
    return Type name = (Type) findViewById(R.id. + id)
}

Input1 = CreateItem(EditText, Input1, InputField);
Input2 = CreateItem(EditText, Input2, InputField2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "UnusedDeclaration" })
  public static <T extends View> T findById(View view, int id) {
    return (T) view.findViewById(id);
  }
```

and this :

```
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "UnusedDeclaration" })
  public static <T extends View> T findById(Activity activity, int id) {
    return (T) activity.findViewById(id);
  }
```

usage:

```
EditText input = findById(this, R.id.InputField);
```

Comment: Why do you suppress UnusedDeclaration?

Comment: Can you explain please or create EditText example

Comment: Also you will need a version which takes an Activity.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice UnusedDeclaration is just suppress the android studio tip when you did not use this method.

Comment: Should it be `findById<EditText>()`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need this library: [Android Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)